# LinkedIn Authorization Code Flow (3-legged OAuth) – Connect to Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, linkedin-api, azure-data-factory

I have registered the LinkedIn API in LinkedIn developer portal and able to generate the ClientID/ Client Secret and also able to generate the code while using the redirect link in web (https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&scope=r_liteprofile&state=123456&redirect_uri=https://xxxxx.com/) and also able to generate the access token (POST- https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken) by using the postman but could not able to understand how this can be done in Azure data factory , I can understand we have the REST API which can retrieve the token and copy the data in ADLS Gen2 but how we can get the code in Azure data factory (without authorization consent)

1. Configure your application in the Developer Portal to obtain Client ID and Client Secret. – This has been done
2. Your application directs the browser to LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 authorization page where the member authenticates. – how this can be handled in ADF
3. After authentication, LinkedIn's authorization server passes an authorization code to your application. – how this can be handled in ADF
4. Your application sends this code to LinkedIn and LinkedIn returns an access token. – This can be done
5. Your application uses this token to make API calls on behalf of the member. – This can be done

As I can understand we need to follow above 5 step and some of steps I can able to manage it.

It would be great help if someone guide me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the new tag so it can reach to LinkedIn and MS

Comment: Have you found a solution?